# Facebook: FQL get all checkins me() is tagged in

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-fql, checkin

I want to get all the checkins a user is tagged in (note: I am not interested in his own checkins). I tried the following, which is a little illogical and of course does not work, but you'll get what I am trying to do:

```
SELECT message FROM checkin WHERE tagged_uids IN 
(SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid = me())
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You're thinking of `IN` backwards. The query you're looking for is:

```
SELECT message FROM checkin WHERE me() IN tagged_uids
```

*However*, `tagged_uids` is [not indexable](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/checkin/), so you'll need to know more information before you can run this query (like who is actually recording the checkin). One thing you could try is:

```
SELECT message FROM checkin 
WHERE author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) 
    AND me() IN tagged_uids
```

This will find all checkins in which your user is tagged that are by friends of the user (probably the only people who can check in that user anyway).

Comment: `tagged_uids` [is an array](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/checkin/), and you don't need to use a column name, any value will do. So yes, you can use `IN`. 

You can certainly query the `tagged_uids` column, but you can't query it *exclusively* - that's what's meant by a field being indexable. Since I have another indexable field in my `WHERE`, that query is valid.

Comment: A small note to future readers. This only works when using me(), as I do not have permission to look through my friends' friends